# How can I determine the lowest value (age) of the top quartile bin using qcut()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I determine the lowest value (age) of the top quartile bin using `qcut()`?

The following DataFrame contains ages:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'age': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
})
```

First, I would like to separate the ages into 4 different bins.  More specifically, I would like to have the same number of ages in each bin.  The first bin would have ages 2 and 4.  The second bin would have 6 and 8.  The third bin would have 10 and 12. And, finally, the fourth bin would have 14 and 16.  I would like to determine the lowest age in the top quartile which would be 14 in this example.

I tried setting `retbins=true` but it only returns the bin values and not the actual age values belonging to each bin.

```
result, bins = pd.qcut(
    df['age'], 
    4,                  # A single number value
    retbins=True
)
```

returns the following:

```
result
0    (1.999, 5.5]
1    (1.999, 5.5]
2      (5.5, 9.0]
3      (5.5, 9.0]
4     (9.0, 12.5]
5     (9.0, 12.5]
6    (12.5, 16.0]
7    (12.5, 16.0]
Name: age, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64, right]): [(1.999, 5.5] < (5.5, 9.0] < (9.0, 12.5] < (12.5, 16.0]]
bins
[ 2.   5.5  9.  12.5 16. ]
```

Is there something that I can use so that my desired output would be `14` in this example?

Comment: Is your array dynamic or fixed?

Comment: If you want to specify the bins use `cut`, not `qcut`.

Comment: @SaiManoj My array will be dynamic.

Comment: @mozway  Each bin should contain the same number of values.  I am only specifying the number of bins and not the spacing.

Comment: Can you provide another input/output example for which the values are not evenly spaced?

Comment: @mozway - I played around with your recommendation using different bin spacings and this worked as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing to get the ages at the max bin, then a simple [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html):

```
result = pd.qcut(df['age'], 4)

out = df.loc[result.eq(result.max()), 'age'].min()
```

Output: `14`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html):

```
>>> df['age'].quantile(0.75, interpolation='higher')
14
```

If your dataframe is well balanced, you can also use [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
groups = np.split(df['age'], 4)  # 4 or len(df) // 2
out = groups[-1].min()

>>> groups
[0    2
 1    4
 Name: age, dtype: int64,
 2    6
 3    8
 Name: age, dtype: int64,
 4    10
 5    12
 Name: age, dtype: int64,
 6    14
 7    16
 Name: age, dtype: int64]

>>> out
14
```

As alternative, use [`np.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html)

Comment: The output differed slightly from qcut() in that it provided a delayed value at different array sizes.  I noticed that the result is still similar to that of qcut()!  Thanks!